# Yii2 rewrite URLs with query string to be SEO

Tags: .htaccess, yii2, friendly-url

What I have could able to make pretty URL in Yii

`example.com/readings/view?BookID=9955`

First, `readings` is my default controller, so I don't want its actions to be prefixed by its name i.e:

`example.com/view?BookID=9955`

Second I need to neglect `?BookID=` to be:

`example.com/view/9955`

Also I have books paging:
`example.com/readings/view?BookID=9955&start=2` I need it to be

`example.com/readings/view/9955/2`

My URLManager config is:

```
'defaultRoute' => 'readings/index',
    //'catchAll' => ['site/offline'],
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => array(               
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
        ],...
```

And `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your rules configuration to reflect what you want it to do.
To make example.com/view?BookID=9955 into example.com/view/9955 you need to:

1) Add the following rule:

```
'view/<BookID:\d+>' => 'readings/view'
```

2) Make sure your controller action is set up to accept the BookID parameter:

```
public function actionView($BookID)
{
   ...
}
```